# jquery plugin or javascript method to auto resize text input(not textarea) (fixed width ) variable height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jquery plugin or javascript method to auto resize text input(not textarea) by height  like  facebook comment box with fixed width and resizable height.

If any one can help me out. I will be thank ful to him

Comment: There are no multiline text type inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize